# Merge two lists of objects into Map having value as different object in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists (say A and B) of same type "MyInfoObject" such that :

```
public class MyInfoObject {
  private Long id;
  private String signature;

  public MyInfoObject(Long id, String signature) {
      super();
      this.id = id;
      this.signature = signature;
  }
}
```

I want to create a Map of these two lists such that all ids of list A and all ids of list B having same signature creates a bucket of type "BucketOfAandB" :

```
public class BucketOfAandB {
  private List<Long> aIds ;
  private List<Long> bIds ;

  public BucketOfAandB(List<Long> aIds, List<Long> bIds) {
    super();
    this.aIds = aIds;
    this.bIds = bIds;
  }
 }
```

So, my output will be `Map<String, BucketOfAandB>`, where key is signature

Eg my input is :

```
    List<MyInfoObject> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(1l, "a"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(2l, "d"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(3l, "b"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(4l, "a"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(5l, "a"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(6l, "c"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(7l, "a"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(8l, "c"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(9l, "b"));
    aList.add(new MyInfoObject(10l, "d"));

    List<MyInfoObject> bList = new ArrayList<>();
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(11l, "a"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(21l, "e"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(31l, "b"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(41l, "a"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(51l, "a"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(61l, "c"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(71l, "a"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(81l, "c"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(91l, "b"));
    bList.add(new MyInfoObject(101l, "e"));
```

My output in this case will be:

```
{
    a= BucketOfAandB[aIds=[1, 4, 5, 7], bIds=[11, 41, 51, 71]],
    b= BucketOfAandB[aIds=[3, 9], bIds=[31, 91]],
    c= BucketOfAandB[aIds=[6, 8], bIds=[61, 81]],
    d= BucketOfAandB[aIds=[2, 10], bIds=null],
    e= BucketOfAandB[aIds=null, bIds=[21, 101]],
}
```

I want to do it using Streams of java 8.

One way I figured out was:

1. create `Map<String, List<Long>>` from `aList`, say aBuckets
2. iterate bList and create `resultant` `Map<String, BucketOfAandB>` by

   - 2a. setting List from aBuckets with same signature to resultant, remove it from `aBuckets`
   - 2b. adding element of `bList` to required signature bucket
3. iterate all remaining elements of `aBuckets` and add them to `resultant`

I want to know a better way to implement this using Streams of Java 8.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I tried using stream but not very happy with implementation. Following is my logic:

```
Map<String, BucketOfAandB> resultmap  = new HashMap<>();

    // get ids from aList grouped by signature
    Map<String, List<Long>> aBuckets = aList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyInfoObject::getSignature,
            Collectors.mapping(MyInfoObject::getId, Collectors.toList())));

    // iterate bList and add it to bucket of its signature
    bList.forEach(reviewInfo -> {
        BucketOfAandB bucket = resultmap.get(reviewInfo.getSignature());

        if(null ==  bucket) {
            bucket = new BucketOfAandB();
            resultmap.put(reviewInfo.getSignature(), bucket);

            List<Long> sourceReviewBucket =  aBuckets.remove(reviewInfo.getSignature());
            if(null !=sourceReviewBucket) {
                bucket.setaIds(sourceReviewBucket);
            }
        }
        bucket.addToB(reviewInfo.getId());
    });

    Map<String, BucketOfAandB> result = aBuckets.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> new BucketOfAandB(e.getValue(), null)));

    resultmap.putAll(result);
```

Comment: If you add the implementation of your algorithm it might be easier to convert it to streams and lambda n stuff.

Comment: What is the logic behind seperating datas into a,b,c,d,e ? If you tell us it can be helpful.

Comment: @JackFlamp I added my implementation in above edit. hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add getters to `MyInfoObject`, and have `BucketOfAandB` lazy initialize its lists (ie no constructor) like this:

```
public class BucketOfAandB {
    private List<Long> aIds;
    private List<Long> bIds;
    public void addAId(Long id) {
        if (aIds == null) {
            aIds = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        aIds.add(id);
    }
    public void addBId(Long id) {
        if (bIds == null) {
            bIds = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        bIds.add(id);
    }
}
```

you can do it in just 3 lines while retaining the semantics of your intention:

```
Map<String, BucketOfAandB> map = new HashMap<>();
aList.forEach(o -> map.computeIfAbsent(o.getSignature(), s -> new BucketOfAandB())
  .addAId(o.getId()));
bList.forEach(o -> map.computeIfAbsent(o.getSignature(), s -> new BucketOfAandB())
  .addBId(o.getId()));
```

If you’re using parallel streams, `synchronize` the add methods, which will add practically no performance hit since it’s only a potential collision on the bucket.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This works perfectly fine and takes lesser time than my implementation.

Comment: @Mak be careful when you say "lesser", measuring some algorithm in java is not easy, by any means

Comment: @eugene simplest is best.

Comment: @Bohemian say that to `TimSort`, please

Comment: I tried using same set of input. Also ran the implementation around 30 times. Please let me know if I need to consider any other parameter to check performance.

Comment: @Eugene I consider TimSort to be simple too.

Comment: @Bohemian is that mocking to mocking? I could come up with an example, of course. Point is unless a target test is in place (let's say with `jmh`), this is called guessing.

Comment: @Mak are you looking for raw speed at the expense of slight complexity?

Comment: Even better than `.getAIds().add(o.getId())` and `.getBIds().add(o.getId())` would be to add methods `addAId(...)` and `addBId(...)` to `BucketOfAandB`, respectively.

Comment: @fed you’re right. I was on the edge of lazy initializing the lists, but your idea give me an “in”. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
    Map<String, List<Long>> mapA = aList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    MyInfoObject::getSignature,
                    Collectors.mapping(MyInfoObject::getId, Collectors.toList())));

    Map<String, List<Long>> mapB = bList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    MyInfoObject::getSignature,
                    Collectors.mapping(MyInfoObject::getId, Collectors.toList())));

    Map<String, BucketOfAandB> overAll = new HashMap<>();

    Set<String> allKeys = new HashSet<>();
    allKeys.addAll(mapA.keySet());
    allKeys.addAll(mapB.keySet());

    allKeys.forEach(x -> overAll.put(x, new BucketOfAandB(mapA.get(x), mapB.get(x))));
```

But this assumes that each key present in `listA` will be present in `listB`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But, since we are iterating on mapA, it will miss  `e= [aIds=null, bIds=[21, 101]` entry.

Comment: `aList` and `bList` can have records present in one and absent in other. Also, both of these list hold a lot of data therefore performance is also important here.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like :

```
Function<List<MyInfoObject>, Map<String, List<Long>>> toLongMap =
      list -> list.stream()
                  .collect(groupingBy(MyInfoObject::getSignature,
                                      mapping(MyInfoObject::getId, toList())));

Map<String, List<Long>> aMap = toLongMap.apply(aList);
Map<String, List<Long>> bMap = toLongMap.apply(bList);

Map<String, BucketOfAandB> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
aMap.forEach((sign, listA) -> {
    finalMap.put(sign, new BucketOfAandB(listA, bMap.get(sign)));
});
bMap.forEach((sign, listB) -> {
    finalMap.putIfAbsent(sign, new BucketOfAandB(null, listB));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This implementations works fine. The time taken is almost equal to my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, first you can create a `Map<String, List<Long>>` and then build the `Map<String, BucketOfAandB>`:

```
Map<String, List<Long>> idsBySignatureA = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyInfoObject::getSignature,
        Collectors.mapping(
            MyInfoObject::getId,
            Collectors.toList())));

Map<String, List<Long>> idsBySignatureB = bList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        MyInfoObject::getSignature,
        Collectors.mapping(
            MyInfoObject::getId,
            Collectors.toList())));

Map<String, List<BucketOfAandB>> result = Stream.concat(idsBySignatureA.entrySet().stream(), idsBySignatureB.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(entry -> 
            new BucketOfAandB(
                idsBySignatureA.get(entry.getKey()),
                idsBySignatureB.get(entry.getKey())), 
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Also feel free to extract the first part into a function for a better readability.